# How to access a specific Angular component from an external URL?

Tags: angular, azure, .net-core

I have a single page angular application that has a .NET Core back-end and is hosted on Azure.

The application allows users to reset their password if they have forgotten it, and the process it follows is that an email is sent to the user with a link to reset the password.

However, when I click the link I get a '404 Page not found' error, I understand that this is because the page doesn't exist as what I want the user to see is a component within the SPA.

I have routing setup, which works correctly when I run it in development but not when it is hosted.

Is there anyway that this can be achieved, either through code or adjusting my Azure Web App Service?

My Routing:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  {
    path: '',
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
    canActivate: [AuthenticateGuard],
    children: [
      { path: 'downloads', component: MenuDownloadsComponent },
      { path: 'user-profile', component: UserProfileComponent }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
    canActivate: [ManagerGuard],
    children: [
      { path: 'manager-dashboard', component: DashboardManagerComponent },
      { path: 'history', component: MenuHistoryComponent }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
    canActivate: [AdminGuard],
    children: [
      { path: 'admin-dashboard', component: DashboardAdminComponent },
      { path: 'user-admin', component: MenuAdminUserComponent },
      { path: 'company-admin', component: MenuAdminCompanyComponent },
      { path: 'software-admin', component: MenuAdminSoftwareComponent },
      { path: 'release-admin', component: MenuAdminReleaseComponent },
      { path: 'item-admin', component: MenuAdminItemComponent },
      { path: 'release-type-admin', component: MenuAdminTypeReleaseComponent },
      { path: 'item-type-admin', component: MenuAdminTypeItemComponent },
      { path: 'uploads', component: MenuUploadsComponent }
    ]
  },
  { path: 'password-reset', component: UserPasswordResetComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

Comment: Can you show your routing config code

Comment: Can you please show routing config code ?

Comment: @TonyNgo  please find my routing config above in the edit

Comment: Do you really need to make the functionality of "Forgot Password" in angular? Your issue can be easily resolved if you use MVC Controller, Action & View for this purpose (generating the link and redirecting on clicking the same), as you are already using .NET Core for back-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the answer to this, and it lay in the Azure Web App Settings

You need to add a path mapping to resolve the redirection to the component you need, see the attached screenshot:

[image: Path Mappings]

To find the path I needed, I had to access the FTP, the address of this in Azure can be found in the Deployment Centre tab, under 'FTP/Credentials':

[image: FTP]

Answer (score 0):

You are define wrong in these route

```
{
    path: '', // need some route here
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
    canActivate: [AuthenticateGuard],
    children: [
      { path: 'downloads', component: MenuDownloadsComponent },
      { path: 'user-profile', component: UserProfileComponent }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '', // need some route here
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
    canActivate: [ManagerGuard],
    children: [
      { path: 'manager-dashboard', component: DashboardManagerComponent },
      { path: 'history', component: MenuHistoryComponent }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '', // need some route here
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
    canActivate: [AdminGuard],
    children: [
      { path: 'admin-dashboard', component: DashboardAdminComponent },
      { path: 'user-admin', component: MenuAdminUserComponent },
      { path: 'company-admin', component: MenuAdminCompanyComponent },
      { path: 'software-admin', component: MenuAdminSoftwareComponent },
      { path: 'release-admin', component: MenuAdminReleaseComponent },
      { path: 'item-admin', component: MenuAdminItemComponent },
      { path: 'release-type-admin', component: MenuAdminTypeReleaseComponent },
      { path: 'item-type-admin', component: MenuAdminTypeItemComponent },
      { path: 'uploads', component: MenuUploadsComponent }
    ]
  },
```

You need to have a path for `path: '',`. Right now I see you have 4 route config have same value `path: ''`. So you need to some route for another 3. Because you have default route for HomeComponent

Comment: Along with above solution use hashing strategies in the ngmodule providers

Comment: @tonyngo I am not sure what you mean, as I am using guards so that only certain people can access certain areas of the application, the path's need to be like this (or I have been led to believe this is the way to do it)